How is it possible that the shortest path in a certain space approaches but never reaches a value? Is distance in this example well-defined?
Consider a space consisting of two horizontal lines at y=0 and y=1, as well as vertical lines at x=(1/n) where n is any natural number. This is the same as the deleted comb space with a top to it. What is the value of the distance between [0,0] and [0,1]? It can't be equal to 1, because there is no line at x=0. Nevertheless, there are infinitely many paths between the two points whose distance approaches 1, a path for each line at x=(1/n). For instance, the path at x=0.1 gives a distance of 1.2. The path at x=0.01 gives a distance of 1.02. x=0.001 gives 1.002.
As you can see this value is approaching 1 but never reaches it. So what is the distance between the two points in this space? Is the problem that this space is not well defined as a metric space? How is that possible if it is contained in a well-defined metric space (the Euclidean plane) and is path-connected. Is d([0,0],[0,1])=1 after all? Does it make sense to define distance in the limit like this?

The subspace is a metric space if you define $d((0,0),((0,1))=1$. A metric is not defined by the length of any path between two points. (In $\Bbb R^n$ the usual metric coincides with the length of the shortest path, but this is not required of a metric space in general.)

One simply defines distance not as minimum but infimum of lengths. This leads to the notion of a path-metric space.

@TonyK That makes sense. I suspected my reasoning that it has to be a metric space because it was in a metric space was off. What is \BbbR^n ?

"It has to be a metric space because it was in a metric space": This is correct! You can simply use the metric of the embedding space as the metric for the embedded space (as I did in my comment). The embedded space doesn't even have to be connected. (And \BbbR^n was just a LaTex typo, now fixed.)

@Moishe Kohan I see. Based on your reply I found the wikipedia article about Intrinsic Metric which I think answers my question.

@TonyK I think I understand. I can have a disconnected metric on this space from the one for Euclidean space, but if I want a metric that is also topologically path-connected than I would have to define it. Is that correct?

By the way, a simpler construction is $\Bbb R^2\setminus{(0,0)}$: there's no shortest path between $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$.
